# Does anybody have a document about Openedge server log?

Tags: logging, openedge, appserver

Does anybody have a document about Openedge server log? It is hard to understand what are the appserver log talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See on:

OpenEdge® Development: Debugging and Troubleshooting

Section 5 Logging in OpenEdge